# API Gateway, AWS SAM, Cognito, and Invalid Grant

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I am trying to deploy an API using AWS SAM into API Gateway, I need to have a Cognito Authoriser with Client Credentials OAuth flow.

So far I have a deployment that works...

My Cognito Stack:

```
Resources:
  CognitoUserPool:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
    Properties:
      UserPoolName: !Sub ${pPipelineCode}-${pGITBranch}
      UserPoolTags:
        application: !Ref pPipelineCode

  UserPoolClient:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient
    Properties:
      AllowedOAuthFlows:
        - client_credentials
      GenerateSecret: "true"
      ClientName: !Sub ${pPipelineCode}-${pGITBranch}-client
      RefreshTokenValidity: !Ref InputRefreshTokenValidity
      SupportedIdentityProviders:
        - COGNITO
      AllowedOAuthScopes:
        - !Sub ${UserPoolResourceServer}/read
        - !Sub ${UserPoolResourceServer}/write
      UserPoolId: !Ref CognitoUserPool

  UserPoolResourceServer:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolResourceServer
    Properties:
      UserPoolId: !Ref CognitoUserPool
      Identifier: !Sub ${pPipelineCode}-${pGITBranch}-server
      Name: !Sub ${pPipelineCode}-${pGITBranch}-server
      Scopes:
        - ScopeName: read
          ScopeDescription: read operation
        - ScopeName: write
          ScopeDescription: write operation

  UserPoolDomainResource:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolDomain
    Properties:
      Domain: !Sub ${pPipelineCode}-${pGITBranch}
      UserPoolId: !Ref CognitoUserPool
```

My API Stack:

```
  ServerlessAPILogGroup:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
    Properties:
      RetentionInDays: 30

  CurrentTimeFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: i010/currenttime/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      Events:
        currenttime:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /i010/currenttime
            Method: GET
            RestApiId: !Ref ServerlessAPI

  ServerlessAPI:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: !Ref pStageName
      AccessLogSetting:
        DestinationArn: !GetAtt ServerlessAPILogGroup.Arn
        Format: >-
          $context.requestId, $context.identity.sourceIp, $context.identity.caller,
          $context.identity.user, $context.requestTime, $context.httpMethod, $context.resourcePath,
          $context.status, $context.protocol, $context.responseLength
      TracingEnabled: true
      Auth:
        Authorizers:
          CognitoAuth:
            AuthType: "COGNITO_USER_POOLS"
            AuthorizationScopes:
              - i010-develop-server/read
              - write
            UserPoolArn:
              Fn::ImportValue:
                !Join [":", [!Ref pGITBranch, "CognitoUserPoolArn"]]
            # Identity:
            #   Header: AuthHeader
            #   ValidationExpression: Bearer.*
            #   ReauthorizeEvery: 30
        DefaultAuthorizer: CognitoAuth
        # InvokeRole: CALLER_CREDENTIALS
        # AddDefaultAuthorizerToCorsPreflight: false
        # ApiKeyRequired: false
        # ResourcePolicy:
        #   CustomStatements:
        #     - Effect: Allow
        #       Principal: "*"
        #       Action: execute-api:Invoke
        #       Resource:
        #         - execute-api:/v1/GET/*
        #     - Effect: Deny
        #       Principal: "*"
        #       Action: execute-api:Invoke
        #       Resource:
        #         - execute-api:/v1/GET/*
        #       Condition:
        #         StringNotEquals:
        #           aws:SourceIp: "<MYIP>"
```

Commented out code is all stuff I have on/off to try test this.

However after a few hours of tweaking I can't get any response other than:

```
{"error":"invalid_grant"}
```

Using:

```
curl -X POST --user <clientId>:<secret> 'https://<URL>.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials&scope=i010-develop-server/read' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding:

AllowedOAuthFlowsUserPoolClient: true

To AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient solved the issue